# Android. How test duration execution of method?

Tags: android

I write unit test (`JUnit`, `Espresso`) for Android app.

And I want to test the duration of execution of any method in `Activity`. And my test must be fail if duration more than 1 second.

Is it possible in `Android`?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example:

```
 private long durationTest() {
    long timeBeforeExecution = System.currentTimeMillis();

    someMethod();

    return System.currentTimeMillis() - timeBeforeExecution;  // difference in millis
}

private void someMethod() {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that although it's hard to predict actual execution time as it depends on many factors. With JUnit you could do something like:

```
@Test(timeout=1000) //milliseconds
public void performanceTest() {
    //my code
}
```

This test will fail if not executed under 1000ms and will pass for any other value.

With espresso test I believe you could adjust timeout rules but I don't see how that helps you in any way. UI test my depend on many things, how long it takes to "press" buttons, network response, other threads that have their own time management and depend on other factors. In any case check this:

[Android Doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/rule/DisableOnAndroidDebug.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

// here code to be time measured

Log.i ("Execution time ", "milliseconds : " + System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
```